# Using mysql load for not varchar variable

Tags: mysql, xml, types, command, load

I've made a little research about MySQL's command `LOAD` to load file. And I could't find an answer to my question.

> Is it possible to load data using LOAD clausure from .xml file into other datatype of
>   column than VARCHAR or INT?

For my project I neet to work with double or float data type and most examples I found was working just with varchar and incrementing int for ID of record.

EDIT: Hope this time I'll make things clear.

I have table RECORDS something like this:

```
___________________________________
| ID  | IDPLACE | VALUE | DATETIME |  
| int |  int    | float | datetime |
```

That VALUE can be whatever decimal.

And I have a xml file something like this.

```
<data>
  <DateTime>12/3/2015 19:15:44</DateTime>
  <place value="0.00000">1</place>
  <place value="0.00000">10</place>
  <place value="5.26316">11</place>
  <place value="100.00000">12</place>
  <place value="100.00000">13</place>
  <place value="91.66667">14</place>
  <place value="8.33333">15</place>
  <place value="100.00000">16</place>
  <place value="100.00000">17</place>
  <place value="100.00000">18</place>
  <place value="100.00000">19</place>
  <place value="77.27273">2</place>
  <place value="8.33333">20</place>
  <place value="0.00000">3</place>
  <place value="94.73684">4</place>
  <place value="100.00000">5</place>
  <place value="0.00000">6</place>
  <place value="100.00000">7</place>
  <place value="10.52632">8</place>
  <place value="23.80952">9</place>
</data>
```

Now I'm using C# script to get those data into table row by row using INSERT. From the script I want to make a service.
But I got an idea of create a procedure using LOAD command to insert those data into table without that service, handled only by MySQL server. For DATETIME column I would use TIMESTAMP or DATETIME.NOW so it would not be contained in .xml file.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Did you research the [XML Loading Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)?

Comment: yes, but all topics I found mentioned only examples that loaded xml file into table with varchar columns

Comment: No, the link I sent you shows the requirements for loading rows and fields from an XML document.  If your XML doesn't match one of the available formats then you must preprocess the XML (with XSLT) to produce an XML file that can be imported.  The alternative is to write your own code (Java, Python, Perl) to parse the XML and issue the `insert` statements yourself.

Comment: My problem is that I need to work with that numerical data as numbers to furhter evaluation and datamining, is that possible with XSLT after preprocess??

Comment: You're misunderstanding.  It would be very helpful if you would post a sample of the XML input that you want to load, as well as the definition of the table into which you want to load the data, and describe how the XML values map to columns in the table.

Comment: Just happened ;) Thanks for your effort Jim.

Answer (score -1):

I am not fully understanding your question. If you are asking if you can insert values from .xml into MySql Data table without using column data type VARCHAR my answer is here:

For the float or double, you can use below datatypes:

*FLOAT(M, D)* 
*DOUBLE(M,D)*
*DECIMAL(M, D)* 
Details:You can define the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D)

You also can use parsing before insert or after in select statement like:

myparsedDecimal = CAST(decimalBeforeParse AS DECIMAL(10, 6))

Comment: No, I would not ask about that. Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to know if it's possible to load  xml file into the table(with decimal numeric data type) by sql command load. I can't find any example anywhere.